# Blazor how to log each BeginRequest and EndRequest

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, nlog

At MVC there was a nice way to log information about each request.
at Global.asax.cs there was two methods:

```
Application_BeginRequest()
Application_EndRequest()
```

That allowed the easy way to log information about each request and if combining them was also possible to get information about request length.

```
Application_Error()
```

was also useful when it comes to logging globally information about errors.

Is anything similar for blazor apps? What is the best way to log each request with information about request length? How globally log each error?

Comment: Google: Alternative to `HttpModule` in asp.net core. You can accomplish something similar with an Asp net core Middleware.

Comment: Does your Blazor app even use http calls though..?

Comment: blazor-server-side uses 1 Http request to load. After that you get SignalR messages. Do you really want to log each MouseMove and ButtonClick?

Comment: `UseHttpLogging` was introduced with .Net6 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/HTTP-Request-Logging

Comment: @henkHolterman you are right, of course, I would like to log only part of the events.